# How do i run a HA MongoDB in my kubernetes cluster without Portworx?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, high-availability, kubernetes-helm

I want to have a MongoDB deployment as a service to my database per service type microservice architecture model.
Right now I am using helm packages to deploy mongo db by defining persistent volume and persistent volume claims.

But I want to deploy mongodb as HA with storing data in any EBS or so!
When I checked online for this solution everything suggests it with Portworx. But is there a way to do it without using Portworx?

Any help appreciated.